# SVN authorization failed

Tags: ubuntu, svn, svnserve

I cannot checkout from my SVN repo with the following configuration on Ubuntu:

svnserve.conf:

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
[sasl]
```

authz content:

```
[aliases]

[groups]

[/procode]
kompi = rw
tlevi = rw

[/procode/code]
david = rw
test = rw
```

passwd content:

```
[users]
david = aaa
adam = aaa
levi = aaa
test = aaa
```

my repo is located in /home/kompi/business

I start svnserver with:
 svnserve -d -r /home/kompi/business --log-file /home/kompi/svnservelog.txt

version is: svnserve, version 1.6.12 (r955767)

and contains a procode subdirectory. I try to checkout with tortoiseSVN, with every user, but I always get an Authorization failed error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was that I used the same checkout URL I used with SVN+SSH

svn+ssh://servername/home/kompi/business/procode

But when you use svnserve, the root of the url becomes your repo, so the correct URL will be:

svn://servername/procode

Answer (score 0):

1. I think, you can (have?) to define some rules for / path in authz file: `$authenticated = r` isn't too wide
2. If `/home/kompi/business` **is** repo, you started svnserve wrongly: -r option defines *root of repository collection* and must be parent folder for all and any repository

**PS**: It's better to troubleshoot svn-related problems in CLI: `svn ls /URL/OF/REPO` give you more detailed information

Comment: adding access to the root helped me debug the real problem, which was that I used the wrong URL for checkout. I used the same URL as I use for SVN+SSH, but with svnserve the URL differs

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use something else than TortoiseSVN? I had trouble with it, and to make sure the problem was not TortoiseSVN itself I installed RapidSVN, which worked fine with the same url.

There is definitely something new in TortoiseSVN that does not work with our SVN server. I am not sure what, but they did something, because TortoiseSVN has never failed me before.